# Class template in header

Tags: c++, templates, header

I have a class in which there are structures declared using template. Can't figure out how to describe class structure in the header file

**.cpp file**

```
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

class Statistics {
    private:
        std::map<int, int> *data;

        struct add_first {
            template<class Pair>
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const {
                return value + pair.first;
            }
        };

        struct add_second {
            template<class Pair>
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const {
                return value + pair.second;
            }
        };

        struct add_expectation {
            template<class Pair>
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const {
                return value + (pair.first * pair.second);
            }
        };

    public:
        Statistics(std::map<int, int> *load_data) {
            data = load_data;
        }

        double get_mean() {
            return std::accumulate((*data).begin(), (*data).end(), 0.0, add_first()) / (*data).size();
        }

        double get_expectation() {
            return std::accumulate((*data).begin(), (*data).end(), 0.0, add_expectation()) / std::accumulate((*data).begin(), (*data).end(), 0.0, add_second());
        }
};
```

In the header file I'm trying to write the following code
**.h file**

```
#ifndef STATISTICS_H
#define STATISTICS_H

#include <map>

class Statistics {
    private:
        std::map<int, int> *data;
        struct add_first {
            template<class Pair>;
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const;
        };
        struct add_second {
            template<class Pair>;
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const;
        };
        struct add_expectation{
            template<class Pair>;
            int operator()(int value, const Pair& pair) const;
        };
    public:
        Statistics(std::map<int, int> *load_data);
        double get_mean();
        double get_expectation();
};

#endif
```

But under this definition, compiler generates an error that the identifier `Pair` is not defined. What's wrong?

Comment: The problem is in the extra semicolons. But see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't define the class both in the header and in its implementation file.

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing the extra semicolons. However, after eliminate compilation errors remained.

Answer (score 1):

After taking all suggentions by @Angew, there should be no error.

1. remove extra colon.
2. define class only in header files.